# Length of a text list in MySQL (basic string manipulation)

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a field of comma-separated lists in MySQL:

```
id field1
1 aa,bb,cc
2 aa
```

I would like to count the total number of elements, with overlap. In this case that would be 4: `aa` appears twice and so should be double-counted.

It would suffice to count the number of commas in each field and add 1, since my lists do not have quotes or escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try that:

```
select count(field1) + sum(CHAR_LENGTH(field1) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(field1,',','')))
from Table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use comma separated string?

Databases aren't made for that.

You have 2 possibilities :
- make a loop in a stored procedure,
- count it into the code which call this MySQL query...

Comment: And can you create a stored procedure?